# TRANSMIT 16QAM 5MHz Signal Via NI USRP 2900

Tags: software-defined-radio, usrp

I am trying to generate 5MHz signal. I am using NI USRP with matlab. I have extended the existing MATLAB QPSK Tx Rx to 16QAM, Now i am struggling with advacing the testbed to send and receive 5MHz signal. At Tx side i have Bits generator, 16QAM Modulator, Raised cosine transmit filter with rolloff factor 0.5 and finally SDR. I am attaching necessary parameter here.
**SimParams.Rsym = 4e6; % Symbol rate in Hertz

SimParams.ModulationOrder = 16;% 16QAM alphabet size

SimParams.Interpolation = 8;% Interpolation factor (Raised cosine filter)

SimParams.Tsym = 1/SimParams.Rsym;  % Symbol time in sec

SimParams.Fs   = SimParams.Rsym * SimParams.Interpolation; % Sample rate**

**Crucial Part ( Need to know if i generate the 5MHz signal at baseband  how i am going to sample at SDR.)**

master clock rate = 9e6

USRPCenterFrequency       = 915e6;

USRPGain                  = 25;

USRPFrontEndSampleRate    = SimParams.Rsym * 2; % Nyquist sampling theorem;

USRPInterpolationFactor   = SimParams.MasterClockRate/SimParams.USRPFrontEndSampleRate;

USRPFrameLength = SimParams.Interpolation * SimParams.FrameSize;

Kindly write what other factor does the signal bandwidth depends on. Is there any formula through which i can calculate my bandwidth, how SDR play its role here

Comment: 9e6 is not a valid master clock rate, and it's also not, as necessary, a multiple of the sample rate. You should see a definite warning to that end. This all really feels more of a programming than a signal processing problem …

Comment: So in USRP, how should i configure my parameter i.e Master clock rate, Interpolation factor, and baseband samplerate which can be obatianed by dividing the Masterclockrate/Interpolation factor

Comment: That's a bit broad a question. I have no idea what your requirements are, and the ones you state aren't sufficient to answer your question.